# Colorspace Difference in OpenCV and MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

I am aware that OpenCV read colored image as BGR by default and MATLAB read colored image as RGB. I both converted same image to L*a*b* colorspace using the code below.

OpenCV Python

```
img=cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
lab=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
cv2.imshow("Sample",lab)
```

MATLAB

```
img=imread("sample.jpg")
D = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab=applycform(img,D);
imshow(lab)
```

However, the image displayed does not have the same output. But when I swap the L* and b* channel in OpenCV, it displays the same image as MATLAB does.

```
img=cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
lab=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l,a,b=cv2.split(lab)
lab=cv2.merge((b,a,l))
cv2.imshow("Sample",lab)
```

Which leads me to the question that do I have to always the replace the first and third channel of a 3-channel image to display it correctly in OpenCV? Not just L*a*b*, HSV and other colorspaces too. Since BGR is displayed as RGB. That does means L*a*b* is displayed as b*a*L* so I have to invert it again to have the correct displayed output?

Comment: OpenCV and probably matlab as well shows an image imaging it is in the default colorspace... this means that OpenCV shows it thinking is a BGR image and the other one probably as RGB. So if you want to mix the two of them you need to convert them to get the same image (just for display and some counted functions(like save)), however internally probably is the same. Also, in python  opencv you do not need to do split and merge, you can do `bal = lab[:, :, ::-1]` and it will change it automatically

Comment: You could probably write that as the answer.